# How to create String from known elements of char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, string-concatenation

I have a `char` array from string:

```
public class CharIndexes {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String a = "A good example is the best sermon.";
        int len = a.length();
        char[] tempA = new char[len] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             tempA[i] = a.charAt(i);
        }
}
```

I need to create 2 strings: `a1` from elements `[3],[0],[28]` and `a2` from: `[15],[24]` and to get a string equal to `'oasis'` (i.e. 3,0,28 elements + 15,24):

```
System.out.println(a1.concat(a2));
```

What can I do?

Comment: `tempA[i] =3D` - What.. is.. this?

Comment: `tempA[i] = a.charAt(i);` ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the choice of characters prints "oAeis" and not "oasis".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...?

```
String a = "A good example is the best sermon.";
char[] c = a.toCharArray();

String a1 = new String(new char[]{c[3],c[0],c[28]});
String a2 = new String(new char[]{c[15],c[24]});

System.out.println(a1+a2);
```

Comment: You should use StringBuilder for performance issues when you are programatically handling string elements and modifying its contents.

Comment: `a` is a string, you defenetely mean the char array `tempA`.

Comment: @BorisBrodski agreed, but thought it'd be better to just use `toCharArray()` rather than building `tempA` in a `for` loop - I saw this as a way to improve on the OPs code.

Comment: @WATTOStudios no more comments after your last edit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = new StringBuffer().append(a.charAt(...)).append(...).toString();
String b = new StringBuffer().append(a.charAt(...)).append(...).toString();
System.out(a.concat(b));
```

Comment: Are other solutions more readable? The problem to solve is pretty particular...you can go newline if you don't want a line too long

Comment: fair call :) I revoke my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of chars like this

```
char [] a1 = new char[] {tempA[3], tempA[0], tempA[28]};
char [] a2 = new char[] {tempA[15], temp[24]};
```

Then you can build your target string as simple as this

```
System.out.println(new String(a1) + new String(a2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how oasis would get formed:

```
String string = "A good example is the best sermon.";
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

String firstPart = new String(new char[] { chars[3], chars[0], chars[28] });
String secondPart = new String(new char[] { chars[15], chars[24] });

String oasis = firstPart.concat(secondPart);
```

Or,

```
String string = "A good example is the best sermon.";
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

StringBuilder firstPart = new StringBuilder().append(chars[3]).append(chars[0]).append(chars[28]);
StringBuilder secondPart = new StringBuilder().append(chars[15]).append(chars[24]);

String oasis = firstPart.append(secondPart).toString();
```

Comment: String dnt have append method,switch to stringBuffer or use concat method

Comment: Typo. Concat. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CharIndexes 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String a = "A good example is the best sermon.";
        int len = a.length();
        char[] tempA = new char[len] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
             tempA[i] = a.charAt(i);
        }
        String a1 = new String (tempA[3]+""+tempA[9]+""+tempA[27]);
        String a2 = new String (tempA[15]+""+tempA[24]);
        System.out.print(a1+a2);
    }
}
```